# why the attribute error arise while doing pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am at learning phase of pygame , the python code shows the attribute error
here is the code

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import (
    K_DOWN,
    K_UP,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    K_ESCAPE,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT)
pygame.init()#initailaze the window
SCREEN_WIDTH = 600
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600
screen_display = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH , SCREEN_HEIGHT])
#variable to keep loop running
running = True
#main loop begins here
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
             running = False
    screen_display = screen_display.fill((255,255,255))
    surface = pygame.Surface((50,50))
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    rectangle = surface.get_rect()
    screen_display.blit(surface, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

#and the output comes as

```
pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.7.9)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\project\game\start.py", line 27, in <module>
    screen_display.blit(surface, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))
AttributeError: 'pygame.Rect' object has no attribute 'blit'
```

Comment: `screen_display = pygame.display.set_mode([SCREEN_WIDTH , SCREEN_HEIGHT])` returns a `pygame.Surface` object. `screen_display = screen_display.fill((255,255,255))` returns a `pygame.Rect` object. `pygame.Rect` has no `blit` attribute, hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the lines

> ```py
> screen_display = screen_display.fill((255,255,255))
> ```

In this line you reassign the return value of `screen_display.fill` to the variable `screen_display`. The return value of [`pygame.Surface.fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) is a `pygame.Rect` object including the affected Surface area.

Change the instruction:

<s>`screen_display = screen_display.fill((255,255,255))`</s>

```py
screen_display.fill((255,255,255))
```